# Элементы массива htmlspecialchars в PHP

Tags: массивы, html, php, функции

Я подгружаю файл с массивом

```
$tool = array(
   'site_name'=>'То, что будет отображаться в теге <title>',
);
```

При выводе тег <title> не отображается, а обрабатывается, как HTML тег. Как все элементы массива $tool пропустить через функцию htmlspecialchars()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто все элементы прогнать, то так:

```
foreach ($tool as &$t){
   $t=htmlspecialchars($t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам надо обрабатывать HTML-код, как обычный текст, то советую использовать функцию для кодирования [htmlentities()](http://www.php.su/functions/?htmlentities) и для обратного декодирования - [htmlentities()](http://www.php.su/functions/?htmlentities)[html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.su/functions/?html-entity-decode)[htmlentities()](http://www.php.su/functions/?htmlentities)

Таким образом прогоняете все элементы массива в цикле **foreach()**

**P.S** Вторым параметром обеих функций должно быть "**ENT_QUOTES**"